# How to change the Color of SwiftUI redacted shimmer effect

Tags: swiftui, placeholder, shimmer

I added a shimmer effect for my home screen like the code below.

```
VStack{
  TopView()
  HomeView()
}
.redacted(.placeholder)
```

I got the output like the below image.

https://ibb.co/xFXQ2sk

the shimmer view showing color for the colored view but the normal view shows gray colored.

can i change the whole shimmer view into gray color without showing the colored view in shimmer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach might be to adjust your custom subviews to respond to whether they're being asked to display as a redaction.

For example, if you have a view that adds a piece of text within a red background, e.g.:

```swift
struct LabelView: View {
  var text: String

  var body: some View {
    Text(text)
       .padding()
       .background(Color.red)
  }
}
```

you could then adapt it to use grey when being redacted:

```swift
struct LabelView: View {
  @Environment(\.redactionReasons) var redactionReasons
  var text: String

  var body: some View {
    Text(text)
       .padding()
       .background(redactionReasons.contains(.placeholder) ? Color.gray : Color.red)
  }
}
```

Comment: yup Thanks, using this method I got the result what i want, but i need to check for each subviews background Color and we need to declare environment in each struct view. is there a way to be written Environment in common class.

Comment: I don't think there is, really. When you're building a custom view that needs to work with redaction, you can leave it to your subviews – texts, images, etc. – to implement their default behaviour or. But when that doesn't work , and the default redaction leaves in elements which you don't want, like background colours, you have to step in and tell your own views how to redact themselves.

Comment: If you find yourself writing the same custom redaction code over and over, you could extract that common code – say, create your own `redactableBackground` modifier and use that instead of `background`. That would cut down on the amount of custom redaction code scattered around the place.

Comment: 'redactableBackground' will be good idea. I will try that